# How can i kick someone with a Discord bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am new to coding and made a Discord Bot, that can Ban users. When i try to change it into kick instead of ban it wont work. Thanks for the help!

```
client.on(`message`, async (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot || message.channel.type === 'dm') return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === `kick`) {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('Nö, kein Bock!')

        const member = message.mentions.members.first()

        if (!member) return message.reply('Es wurde kein Member erwähnt!')

        if (!member.bannable) return
        message.guild.members.kick(member)

        
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it right.  [`kick()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick) is a function that only works on a [member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object. So you need to use the `member` that you defined in your code directly.

```
// this is the member that you defined in your code.
member.kick();
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!!! Ive been sittng on this problem for hours!

Comment: no, `kick()` only takes one parameter and that is the reason. By default that is none. Check the links I provided if you want to know more about that.